# How can you add a field value to css?

Tags: entities, theming

I know this is possible in views -> style settings of a field, but what if you can't customize the fields?

I would like to add css to the mini calendar from the calendar-module depending on the value of a field called 'field_location'.

**So `class="fri mini future has-events "` becomes `class="fri mini future has-events field_location"`**

I copied the calendar-mini.tpl.php and on line 49 I changed

```
< td id=" < ?php print $cell['id']; ? >" class="< ?php print $cell['class']; ? >">
```

into:

```
< td id=" < ?php print $cell['id']; ? >" class="< ?php print $cell['class'] ' ' . $node->field_location['und'][0]['value']; ? >">
```

If I use `$node = node_load(736);` it works, but it adds the 'field_location' of that node to all classes. 
I need to place the right 'field_location' in the right class.

Comment: You most probably have to look into whatever is in `$cell['data']` and then based upon that determine what should be wrapping it, eg, what classes should be added.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
It took me some time to figure out what's happening in the $cell['data'] part, but I can't figure out how I could use it.

I also tried replacing 

$node->field_location['und'][0]['value']; 

with

< ?php foreach($nodes as $events): print $events->field_location['und'][0]['value']; ? > < ?php endforeach; ? >

But then it prints all the field locations after every class. So maybe I'm a small step closer?
How can I determine that it puts only the right location behind the rest of the class?

Comment: you're getting closer, you need to figure out which nodes are in each day's cell in your calendar and then apply whatever information you need about those nodes to the cell they are in.  At least that's what I assume you are trying to do.  You will probably have to do this inside the `foreach` in the tpl and reload as you go along.  That *should* cause things to change per cell.  If you do it outside that `foreach` in the template, then yes, this will be applied to each and every cell since you aren't changing it based upon what is inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Copying out the relevant portion of the template:

```
<tbody>
  <?php foreach ((array) $rows as $row): ?>
    <tr>
      <?php foreach ($row as $cell): ?>
        <td id="<?php print $cell['id']; ?>" class="<?php print $cell['class']; ?>">
          <?php print $cell['data']; ?>
        </td>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

If you want the `<td>` wrapping your cell to have an additional class based upon what is inside that cell, you will need to do something like this:

```
<tbody>
  <?php foreach ((array) $rows as $row): ?>
    <tr>
      <?php foreach ($row as $cell): ?>
        <?php
          $new_class= // grab information out of $cell['data']
        ?>
        <td id="<?php print $cell['id']; ?>" class="<?php print $cell['class'] . ' ' .  $new_class; ?>">
          <?php print $cell['data']; ?>
        </td>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

If it's not easy to do, `$cell['data']` is probably HTML since it is just being printed, you do have the entire `$view` object to work with, and there, you can grab stuff out of `$view->result` and correlate that to these cells.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer again!
The $cell['data'] looks like some uneditable stuff, so I was going for an array or object of $view->result.
But I still haven't figured it out properly.

Comment: I replaced the line '$new_class= // grab information out of $cell['data']'
with: ' $type = "event"; //name of content type
  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type));
  foreach($nodes as $events):
   $new_class=$events->field_location['und'][0]['value'] ;'

But this messes up the calendar. I'm sorry I just can't see the clear picture here. I feel like that labrador-meme

Comment: If I print '$new_class=$products->field_location['und'][0]['value'] ;' I get a list with locations, so this part works.

I don't know what to change in this foreach since it messes up the calendar. It now repeats every day for every event(node?) I have. Say I have 5 events, my calendar looks like: 11111222223333344444... The class is added in the code, but also repeated. I can feel I'm close, but I'm still facing a wall.

Comment: without seeing your actual code, I can only guess, but adding something *inside* a `foreach()` loop *shouldn't* change the loop itself

Comment: Sorry, I added my code as an answer for a better view.

Comment: yes, it looks like you are now looping through all events instead of finding what events are in that actual cell and then using just that node's location.

Comment: I have to put this in the fridge, for now, since it's taking too much time. If I find something later I'll post it here.
Thanks.

Comment: So I've been looking at this again and I'm still not seeing what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: So I've been looking at this again and I'm still not seeing what I'm doing wrong here.

Does anybody know how you can print a field value?
Let's say you have a View that imports fields from a content type "Event" and you want to print the value of the field "Location" (somewhere in your code, in my case ass css)
Do you have to use the $view->result as spoken above OR can you use the $item or $field variable too?
$item->title returns the name, but anything else gives me errors.